# $scope variable being copied, not referenced in Kendo-UI window

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a situation where I am passing a $scope variable into a Kendo-UI window, and any changes being made

All of this sits in one controller.

So in my main controller, I have a $scope.searchTerm variable which I initialise to "Enter search term"..

in my HTML, I call  peopleSearch.open() as below on my main controller

```
<td><span>GSP</span><span ng-click="peopleSearch.open()" style="font-size:8pt;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span><td>
```

This simply opens this kendo-ui window declared below, and covered by the same controller:

```
<div kendo-window="peopleSearch" k-title="'Person Search'"
                            k-width="900" k-height="500" k-visible="false"
                            k-content="{ url: 'parts/peopleSearch.html' }"
                            k-on-open="peopleSearchVisible = true" k-on-close="peopleSearchVisible = false"
                            k-modal="true"></div>
```

The Kendo-UI window template, again, covered by the same controller is as below.  Note that there is an input bound to $scope.searchTerm.  When the window opens, the input is initialised with "Enter search term"...so it is obviously bound the $scope.searchTerm variable.

```
<section>
<div class="myAlerts">
        <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" >{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>  
<div>People Search</div><br/>
<div>{{searchTerm}}</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" style="width:400px;"</input><span>  Enter surname or part of surname to search the Active Directory</span>
<br/><br/>
<button ng-click="performSearch()"  class="form-control" style="width:400px;">Search</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>   
    <div>{{searchTerm}}</div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" style="cell-padding:0px;cell-spaing:0px;font-size:10pt;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Initials</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <td>Office</td>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>             
            </tr>           
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
            <tr ng-repeat="people in peopleResults">
                <td>{{people.displayName[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{people.initials[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{people.title[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{people.physicalDeliveryOfficeName[0]}}</td>               
                <td>{{people.mail[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{people.company[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{people.department[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{people.telephoneNumber[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{people.mobile[0]}}</td>
                <td></td>               
            </tr>       
        </tbody>        
    </table>
</div>
</section>
```

However, when I start typing and press perform the search:

```
$scope.performSearch = function() 
        {
                prPeopleService.findPeople($scope.searchTerm).then(function(people) {
                    $scope.peopleResults = people;
                    $scope.addAlert('success', $scope.peopleResults.length + ' people located');
                },
                function(response) {
                    $scope.addAlert('danger', 'There was an issue trying to look people up from the Active Directory...');
                });
        };
```

The $scope.searchTerm being passed in as a parameter is the initial "Enter Search Term"...and not the value being entered into the input field...which is bound to $scope.searchTerm....as if it took a copy to start with, then decided to detach itself.

Comment: try to make searchcontent as object intead of string like $scope.searchTerm={value:''} and use input ng-model as searchTerm.value

Comment: trying now, thanks.  So I can't use string variables for 2 way binding and passing around as function parameters?

Comment: works by the way ;-), just need to understand why I can't pass string variables around on the scope.

Comment: read this to understand https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Hi, thanks, although I am not using a child scope as far as I am aware, all this is happening in the same controller?

Comment: I assume it something to do with how the directive for kendo-ui window uses scope in its directive somehow?